# rubygems IOError: Function not implemented (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, freebsd, rbenv

I installed Oracle Java on FreeBSD 10:

```
bb@rails:~/redmine-2.5.1 % java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Also, I have jruby 1.7.12 under rbenv running on top of that:

```
bb@rails:~/redmine-2.5.1 % jruby -v
jruby 1.7.12 (1.9.3p392) 2014-04-15 643e292 on Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.8.0_05-b13 +indy [linux-i386]
```

jirb works just fine:

```
bb@rails:~/redmine-2.5.1 % jirb
irb(main):001:0> 2+3
=> 5
irb(main):002:0>
```

When I try to install a gem (the first one I need is bundler), I get an odd error message:

```
bb@rails:~/redmine-2.5.1 % jruby -S gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - IOError: Function not implemented (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I've tried to download rubygems from http instead, but results aren't any better:

```
bb@rails:~/redmine-2.5.1 % jruby -S gem install bundler --source http://rubygems.org/
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - IOError: Function not implemented (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - IOError: Function not implemented (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `curl https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz -I`?

Comment: `bb@rails:~/redmine-2.5.1 % curl https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz -I`
`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`
`Server: nginx`
`Date: Sat, 26 Apr 2014 16:51:07 GMT`
`Content-Type: text/html`
`Content-Length: 154`
`Connection: keep-alive`
`Location: https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz`

Comment: `bb@rails:~/redmine-2.5.1 % curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz -I`
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`x-amz-id-2: fhTEs7XGjkms8BAxguhdIJnygkLfj2N3SehozYQDmupxj5Gk/gimeLAspx2QlpkzLNQUnSWiXHQ=`
`x-amz-request-id: 20696E6ED7267322`
`Date: Sat, 26 Apr 2014 16:51:45 GMT`
`Last-Modified: Sat, 26 Apr 2014 16:49:48 GMT`
`x-amz-version-id: H80D7eCxggOPuoZhRzJZsoXNMjs5PG2B`
`ETag: "3f383aec6442ac3f55567f84af606edb"`
`Accept-Ranges: bytes`
`Content-Type: `
`Content-Length: 610014`
`Server: AmazonS3`

Comment: are you running that from within redmine or something?

Comment: No, just from a normal shell. Just trying to get redmine up and running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1. Install Oracle Java + JRuby on the FreeBSD host itself, not inside a jail.
2. User Rubinius or MRI instead